# Is it possible to get only the header without fetching the body using the requests.get command? the server is blocking HEAD

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, http-headers

In a configuration I am using, a minio server hosting files, accepts only GET requests and does not accepts HEAD requests. I need the header information to check for file-type to avoid fetching the entire file.

I would do it usually with `requests.head(url)` however as I mentioned earlier only the GET method is allowed.

In curl it is possible to do the following:

`curl -I -X GET http://domain.dom/path/`

which curls the header of the url but overrides the used method with the GET HTTP method.
Is there something equivalent for the Python3 `requests` package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a clean way to do this. If the server accepts `Range` header, you could try requesting the bytes from 0 to 0, which nets you access to the header data but not the body. For example

```
import requests   

url = "http://stackoverflow.com"
headers = {"Range": "bytes=0-0"}
res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(res.headers)
```

As said, this still depends on the server implementation. For reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Range

Answer (score 1):

Based on [the definition of a GET](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-get), it sounds like you could modify the request headers to include a range-request.

```
A client can alter the semantics of GET to be a "range request", requesting transfer of only some part(s) of the selected representation, by sending a Range header field in the request (Section 14.2).
```

I haven't tried this, but maybe setting a byte range of 0-1 would skip the body and you'd get the headers for free.